# Combining multiple text files in RStudio

Tags: rstudio, text-files

I have this folder of text files and i can not seem to find a way to get r to open all the text files at once. I get an empty list all list.

```
library(readtext)
mypath = "C:/Users/omoruyid9/Downloads/4mW-20191014T020247Z-001"
setwd(mypath)
txt_files_ls = list.files(path=mypath, pattern="*.txt") 
txt_files_df <- lapply(txt_files_ls, function(x) {read.table(file = x, header = T, sep =",")})
combined_df <- do.call("rbind", lapply(txt_files_df, as.data.frame))
```

and this the error code I keep getting.

```
text_files_df.print
Error: object 'text_files_df.print' not found
> print(text_files_df)
Error in print(text_files_df) : object 'text_files_df' not found
> print(txt_files_df)
list()
> View(txt_files_df)
>
```

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to specify your file path again.  I only list.files and it works for me

```
library(readtext)
mypath = "C:/Users/omoruyid9/Downloads/4mW-20191014T020247Z-001"
setwd(mypath)
txt_files_ls = list.files(pattern="*.txt") 
txt_files_df <- lapply(txt_files_ls, function(x) {read.table(file = x, header = T, sep =",")})
combined_df <- do.call("rbind", lapply(txt_files_df, as.data.frame))
```

Comment: I am still getting an empty data list.